# Read from a txt file and assign the value of lines to class fields

Tags: java, file-io, arraylist, collections, file-handling

if anyone can help please ,
i have an issue assign the values from a text file to the class fields.
i have created a class called process and it has a fields like

```
private String  agent;
private String request_type;
private String class_type;
private String num_of_seats;
private String  arrivaltime;
```

my motive is to assign 1block in the file to agent separated by space another block to request type and so on...
say `Agent3 R F 10 1` here Agent3 is going to be assign to agent and R going to assign to request_type  F to class_type, 10 to num_of_seats,1 to arrivaltime

i am using arraylist to saveinput file (not compulsory i know this only thats y) and another arraylist to save the objects of my class.i am using  substring method to assign the values manually is there any way instead of that so  that i can simply take block which is seprated by space and do my job.

The input file(input.txt is )

```
Agent1 R F 2 0
Agent3 R F 10 1
Agent1 C F 1 4
Agent2 C B 2 1
Agent2 R B 10 0
```

................................................................................

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * @author Navdeep
 *
 */
class Process
{
    private String  agent;
    private String request_type;
    private String class_type;
    private String num_of_seats;
    private String  arrivaltime;
    public Process()
    {
        setProcess("0", null, null, "0", "0");
    }

    public Process(String a, String b,String c,String d,String e)
    {

        setProcess(a,b,c,d,e);
    }
    public void  setProcess(String a, String b,String c,String d,String e)
    {
        setAgent(a);
        setRequest_type(b);
        setClass_type(c);
        setNum_of_seats(d);
        setArrivaltime(e);  
    }
    public void setAgent(String a){
        agent = a;

    }
    public void setRequest_type(String b){
        request_type = b;
    }
    public void setClass_type(String c)
    {
        class_type = c;
    }
    public void setNum_of_seats(String d) {
    num_of_seats = d;
    }
    public void setArrivaltime(String e)
    {
        arrivaltime=e;
    }
    public String getAgent(){
        return agent;

    }
    public String getRequest_type(){
        return request_type ;
    }
    public String  getClass_type()
    {
        return class_type; 
    }
    public String  getNum_of_seats() {
    return num_of_seats ;
    }
    public String  getArrivaltime()
    {
        return arrivaltime;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s",getAgent(),getRequest_type(),getClass_type(),getNum_of_seats(),getArrivaltime());
    }

}

public class main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        File temp = new File(args[0]);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(temp);
        ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();

        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
         input.add(sc.nextLine());

        }
        List<Process> mylist = new ArrayList<Process>();    
        for (int i= 0; i <input.size();i++)
        {
        Process processobject = new Process();
        processobject.setAgent(input.get(i).substring(0, 6));

        processobject.setRequest_type(input.get(i).substring(7,8));
        processobject.setClass_type(input.get(i).substring(9,10));
        if(input.get(i).length() == 15)
        {
            processobject.setNum_of_seats(input.get(i).substring(11,13));
            processobject.setArrivaltime(input.get(i).substring(14,15));    
        }
        if(input.get(i).length() == 14)
        {
        processobject.setNum_of_seats(input.get(i).substring(11,12));
        processobject.setArrivaltime(input.get(i).substring(13,14));
        }
        mylist.add(processobject); // fill arraylist with objects of my class
        }
        System.out.println("array list of the input from the file" + input);
        System.out.println("\n \nobjects in my list"+ mylist);
    }
}
```

the overall motive of my project is to sort the objects  according to the field priorities.

Comment: Probably your Process object shouldn't be changed in the future, so maybe you should consider to make fields final and then remove set methods to get nice immutable object.

Comment: @Zano havent get you point exactly what u mean by that

Comment: All I'm saying is that probably u don't want to let anyone or anything to change your Process object values in the future. If so then make it immutable, if not then ignore my previous filthy comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objective is to create Process class instance then you can use the following code:

```
while(sc.hasNext())
{
  String line = sc.nextLine();
  String elements[] = line.split(" ");
  Process processobject = new Process();
  processobject.setProcess(elements[0],elements[1],elements[2],elements[3],elements[4]);
}
```

You can improve the your `setProcess` method by setting accessing directly class attributes with `this` reference. Also you can pass the same parameters to `Process` class constructor then you won't need `setProcess` method. Check the below code.

```
public Process(String agent, String request_type, String class_type, String num_of_seats, String arrivaltime) {
  this.agent = agent;
  this.request_type = request_type;
  this.class_type = class_type;
  this.num_of_seats = num_of_seats;
  this.arrivaltime = arrivaltime;
}
```

Comment: i am using for loop for making objects of my class and putting those in array list.... my objective is to set the value of each field of that object. i am doing it using substring method but the problem of that is if i get any other line which i am not expecting in my code say.

Comment: Agent1 R F 10 1  here simply using string im assigning first 6 elemets to the agent 8th element to the type 10 element to the class 12and 13 to the nummber of seats and 15th element to arrivaltime

Comment: But if input  is Agent1 R F 1 1  i will have a problem to deal with this  as if i use previus method i will get a extra space

Comment: if anymethod which can take the sting elements till space and then pickit and save it and again do this for whole shift

Comment: @Nav just use split(" ") like in the answer above. It will solve all your problems. Using substring like this is straight suicide.

Comment: @Nav The code I have provide will read the lines from file and create the `Process` objects. You need not to worry about extra spaces in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(configFileName).getFile());
        input = new FileInputStream(someFilePath);
        prop.load(input);
        String someString=prop.getProperty("someString");
        int someintValue=new Integer(prop.getProperty("someintValue"));
```